# Crear un archivo .spec.ts usando el CLI de Angular o Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, cli

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y necesito saber **¿si es posible crear un archivo de tipo spec.ts (nombre-componente.spec.ts) en Ionic o Angular?**.

Sé que se crea el archivo por defecto al momento de generar un componente con el CLI `ng generate component` o `ionic generate component`, el problema es que borré el archivo y ahora lo necesito, y no se como generarlo a través del CLI de Ionic o Angular.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente el CLI de Angular no brinda esta funcionalidad, y no está claro cómo y cuándo será posible obtenerla o usarla de manera oficial.

De todas maneras, hay una biblioteca llamada ["ngx-spec"](https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-spec), que genera la especificación basada en los ajustes preestablecidos del CLI de Angular.

Si estás usando Visual Studio Code, los autores de ngx-spec recomiendan usar la extensión [Angular Schematics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cyrilletuzi.angular-schematics).

Si necesitas aun mas, te recomiendo usar el paquete de extensiones: ([Angular Essentials](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gydunhn.angular-essentials)) que te ayudaran con tu desarrollo, y que ya tiene la utilidad de Angular Schematics.